# Zero sets in completely regular spaces

Tags: general-topology

I'm wondering if I am missing something from this portion of a problem (14.C.1 - Willard)

A zero set in a topological space $X$ is a set of the form $f^{-1}(0)$ for some continuous $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

If $f$ is a real-valued continuous function of $X$, then $A=\{x\mid f(x)\geq a\}$ and $B=\{x\mid f(x)\leq a\}$ are zero sets, for each $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

The title of the entire problem is *Zero sets in completely regular spaces.* Can I assume that my space $X$ is completely regular? I don't think so, but I really am stuck right now.

These are my thoughts so far;
It seems that the structure is incorrect, in this case, $f(x)=a$ would be in both $A$ and $B$. Does that just mean that my function is $f(X)=0?$ Clearly not...

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use $f$ to construct another continuous function such that $A$ is the zero set of this function. Take $g(x) = \min(f(x) - a, 0)$. Show that it is continuous and that $A = g^{-1}(0)$. The same idea applies to $B$.

Comment: I get it now, thank you. My mistake came in when I was assuming $A$ and $B$ were zero sets for the function $f$, I had no idea it was referring to another function! Just to confirm $A$ and $B$ are a zero sets of some functions, say $g$ and $h$, and it is alright if $g\neq h$?